# How many structurally different trees can be formed with n nodes?

Tags: data-structures, combinatorics, trees

Is there any exact formula for finding number of structurally different unlabeled trees can be formed with $n$ nodes? I searched a lot and I found some approximation formulas, e.g. [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)).

Comment: Have you tried counting them? In addition to Juho's question, are they ordered/plane? If there's an answer, it's probably in [Flajolet/Sedgewick Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/books.html).

Comment: @Raphael As Juho noted, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)#Unlabeled_trees) states that no closed formula is known.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [A000055](https://oeis.org/A000055). Even if this is not what you want, it is probable that the OEIS has your sequence. The easiest way to look for a sequence in the OEIS is by calculating the first few numbers.

Comment: See also A000081 for rooted trees (mentioned in FrankW's answer).

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, no such formula is known. You can find a generating function, recursion, and first 1000 terms at [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A000081).